# How to stream sound from Android phone to PC?

Tags: wi-fi, streaming, audio

Is there a way to stream all sound from an Android phone to a PC to be played by the boxes of the PC?
At best wirelessly?

Comment: Would bluetooth play all the sounds through the PC?

Comment: @Ivo: What do I have to install on the PC to play the bluetooth stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Based on some quick testing I did on my Nexus One running Android 2.2 (Froyo), it seems like all sound is routed through headphones when they are plugged in.

You could attach a male-to-male 1/8" (3.5mm) audio cable from the headphone jack on your phone (or the mini-USB-to-headphone-jack adapter, depending on your phone model) to the Line In jack on your PC.  You may need to do some configuration on your PC to get sound from the Line In to play to the speakers — I recommend sister site [Super User](https://superuser.com/) if you need help with that.

There's one caveat: although all sound is routed through the headphone jack, some sounds are still also heard through the phone's speakers.  The two most notable of these are the ringer and the camera shutter sound.  Depending on what exactly you're going for, that could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use any DLNA streaming server app on android is one solution. [This is my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/165119/202272) to another similar question which might be useful

> Yes there are. Some which I found are for gaming live streaming like *YouTube Gaming*, *Mobcrush* & *Twitch*. Some for screen mirroring and streaming like *Screen Stream Mirroring Free*. Some streaming videos and audios like *AllConnect - Play & Stream* which supports DLNA/UPnP. Some also make your android a UPnP/DLNA streaming server like *BubbleUPnP UPnP/DLNA*, *MediaHouse UPnP / DLNA Browser*, *Plex & BubbleUPnP for DLNA/Chromecast*.

Of course, this could be done on local network or online via internet connection.