# How to stream audio from Android device to PC or web-server?

Tags: wi-fi, audio, streaming

Is there any ready-made application that allows one to stream audio, over WiFi to from phone's microphone to a configurable IP-address and port-number ?

Have come across several applications that do the reverse, and some that are very purpose specific, i.e. baby-monitor, which do not fit my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are. Some which I found are for gaming live streaming like *YouTube Gaming*, *Mobcrush* & *Twitch*. Some for screen mirroring and streaming like *Screen Stream Mirroring Free*. Some streaming videos and audios like *AllConnect - Play & Stream* which supports DLNA/UPnP. Some also make your android a UPnP/DLNA streaming server like *BubbleUPnP UPnP/DLNA*, *MediaHouse UPnP / DLNA Browser*, *Plex & BubbleUPnP for DLNA/Chromecast*.

Update: Also there Voip over lan apps like *Wi-Fi Talkie FREE*, *WiCall : VoIP call, Wifi call* & *Intercom for Android*,. There is app for streaming android **mic** to Icecast servers called *Cool Mic*. Another streaming via HTTP/RTSP called *LANmic* and another called *RtpMic*.

Sorry I can't post more than 2 links with my new account. I posted the exact names of some examples though. I'm sure there are more but these were on the top of the lists and with massive number of users.